# How to properly inject container to a form file without breaking the CRUD related actions?

Tags: symfony

Currently, this is how I injected container into my form (by making it a service):

ApFloorType.php

```
namespace Techforge\ApartmentBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


class ApFloorType extends AbstractType
{

    //in the controller, they are differently initialised
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {

        $bath_choices = $this->container->getParameter('bath_choices');
        $bed_choices = $this->container->getParameter('bed_choices');

        $builder
            ->add('baths', 'choice', array('choices' => $bath_choices))
            ->add('beds', 'choice', array('choices' => $bed_choices))
            ->add('name')
            ->add('file')
            ->add('plan_description', 'textarea')
            ->add('min_max_feet', 'text')
            ->add('deposit', 'text')
            ->add('application_fee')
            ->add('rental_deposit')
            ->add('lease_terms', 'textarea')
            ->add('threshhold_value')
            ->add('auto_accept')
            ->add('pending')
            ->add('apartment', 'hidden', array('property_path' => false))
            ->add('pre_post_update', 'hidden')
            ->add('photos', 'collection', array('type' => new ApFloorImageType()))

        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'techforge_apartmentbundle_apfloortype';
    }
}
```

The problem is that the ApFloor CRUD system stoped working after this because, in my controller, I couldn't just write

```
$form   = $this->createForm(new ApFloorType(), $floor);
```

This would produce the following error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Techforge\ApartmentBundle\Form\ApFloorType::__construct() must
>   implement interface
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given,
>   called in
>   /home/stormlifter/webapps/pmr/src/Techforge/ApartmentBundle/Controller/Manager/ApFloorController.php
>   on line 38 and defined in
>   /home/stormlifter/webapps/pmr/src/Techforge/ApartmentBundle/Form/ApFloorType.php
>   line 16

I solved this by calling form create method like this;

```
$form   = $this->createForm($this->get('apfloortype'), $floor);
```

So my question is, is there a workaround this so I don't have to change each createForm() call in my CRUD controller after making it a service?

Comment: If you already turned it into a service then make the change. The other way would be to always pass the container when creating a new form: `$this->createForm(new ApFloorType($this->container), $floor);`

Comment: Another thing, if you just need the container to pass the parameters, you could directly pass the parameters to the constructor through your service.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the FormType:

```
$data = Class::getYourData();
```

Because I don;t want (like you) to modify each controller to set extra parameter to the form..